# Syntax highlighting for whole projects is broken

Tags: java, eclipse, git, syntax, highlighting

As you can see, the syntax highlighting of a whole project is gone. Actually I use Eclipse Oxygen with the EGit-Plugin. It is important because at the moment it seems that the problem is hidden somewhere in the project itself.

What i have tried so far:
 - reset settings from eclipse
 - uninstall "Darkest Theme"
 - change the color-scheema
 - manualy change colors for the Java-Editor

Nothing happened. After this I Downloaded a new Eclipse EE, imported the project from Bitbucket and the problem was all the same.
After this I tried to change the computer but it was all the same. That means to me, there was pushed something to the project that causes this changes.

One more special thing about it: there are a few highlights that changed the way they have to...

Some pictures:

Here Is the plain view of some code
[image]

An here is a picture with the Code compared to the way it should look
[image]

I hope you can help me. The last chance should be copying all the classes or code and the rest of the project into a new project...

I hope i gave you as much information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The icon of the file `App.java` is shown grayed. For full edit capabilitys (including colors) the j-character in the icon must be filled blue.

Comment: The grayed icon is a result of a couple of possible problems. Try to use Alt+F5 and `Select all`.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to search for a solution with that hint.
I never used Maven on this project. Moreover I never used Maven before. That means I don't know what to do.
But after pressing Alt+F5 there is nothing to select.

Answer (score 0):

OK, its solved now.
The problem was, the .classpath disappeared and it wasn't recognised as a Java-project anymore. I don't know how this happened, but my problem is solved now.
I created a new project, copied the neccessary files and added the classpaths to the right directories again.

So thanks for the hint with the Icon. I would never have noticed it.